# I'm confused about LaTeX 3 returning values from functions

Tags: expl3, latex3

The below code works as expected and prints on the terminal "answer is 5".  How can I change the code below so I can replace lines B and C with, in pseudocode,

```
set \l_width_int to \width:N \l_test_seq
```

I tried many things around lines A, B, C and other places and couldn't get anything to work.  I'm confused.  Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

  \int_new:N \l_width_int
  \seq_new:N \l_test_seq

  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_test_seq {alpha,beta,gamma}

  % This function sets \l_width_int to the number of characters
  % in the longest element of the sequence argument.
  \cs_new:Npn \width:N #1
    {
      \int_new:N \l__width_curwidth_int
      \int_new:N \l__width_maxwidth_int
      \tl_new:N  \l__width_cur_tl

      \int_set:Nn    \l__width_maxwidth_int {-1}
      \seq_map_inline:Nn {#1}
        {
          \tl_set:Nn  \l__width_cur_tl {##1}
          \int_set:Nn \l__width_curwidth_int {\tl_count:N \l__width_cur_tl}
          \int_compare:nT
            {\l__width_curwidth_int > \l__width_maxwidth_int}
            {\int_set:Nn \l__width_maxwidth_int \l__width_curwidth_int}
        }
      \int_set:Nn \l_width_int \l__width_maxwidth_int    % line A
    }
  \width:N \l_test_seq                                   % line B
  \immediate\write16{answer~is~\int_use:N \l_width_int}  % line C

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

To be able to set `\l_width_int` (or any variable) to the result of a function (really a macro) in TeX, we have to arrange for the calculation to be done by expansion. In `expl3` terms, that means you can only use functions which are shown with a star in `interface3`. To do that, we need to rearrange the code. I'd go with something like

```
\cs_new:Npn \MS_width:N #1
  {
    \seq_map_function:NN {#1} \__MS_width:n
    \__MS_result:n { -1 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MS_result:n #1 {#1}
\cs_new:Npn \__MS_width:n #1 #2 \__MS_result:n #3
  {
    \__MS_width:fnn
      { \int_eval:n { \tl_count:n {#1} } } {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MS_width:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {#3}
      { #2 \__MS_result:n {#1} }
      { #2 \__MS_result:n {#3} }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__MS_width:nnn { f }
```

The idea is to set up the mapping such that the result is kept in the input stream all of the time: I use `\__MS_result:n` as a marker to know where it is and to allow the mapping tokens to be 'moved around'. I also arrange for this to be a simple 'do nothing' function to finally dump the result at the end of the mapping. This would then work in

```
\iow_term:x { answer~is~\MS_width:N \l_MS_test_seq }
```

(I've given your public sequence a 'proper' name here.)

Notice that I've 'forced' evaluation of the length of the token list using `f`-type expansion, so the value is worked out exactly rather than potentially at every pass (if the first item in the list is the longest).

---

I'm using the fact here that I know that I can 'move stuff around' with the sequence mapping. I don't want to rely on a  particular internal form for the sequence so have to stick to `\seq_map_function:NN`. One might argue that it would be better to work directly from the comma list and to therefore know exactly what is going on in all of the code:

```
\cs_new:Npn \MS_width_comma:N #1
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__MS_width:w #1 , \q_nil , \q_stop
      { -1 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MS_width:w #1 , #2 \q_stop #3
  {
    \quark_if_nil:nTF {#1}
      { #3 }
      {
        \__MS_width:fnn { \int_eval:n { \tl_count:n {#1} } }
          {#2} {#3}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__MS_width:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {#3}
      { \__MS_width:w #2 \q_stop {#1} }
      { \__MS_width:w #2 \q_stop {#3} }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__MS_width:nnn { f }
```

The basic idea is of course the same: depending on the nature of your input, you might go either way. (I'm not clear if you start with a user comma list or you might have a sequence with empty items, *etc.*)

Comment: I see egreg has mentioned various other things in [his answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346775/73), so I don't need to ;)

Comment: I've kept `width` as it's the term you've used, but normally that is a typesetting concept: you are really talking about `length`.

Answer (score 2):

You're making things more complicated than needed. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_senn_width_int
\seq_new:N \l_senn_test_seq

\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_senn_test_seq {alpha,beta,gamma}

% This function sets \l_senn_width_int to the number of characters
% in the longest element of the sequence argument.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \senn_width:N #1
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l_senn_width_int {-1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #1
   {
    \int_set:Nn \l_senn_width_int
     {
      \int_max:nn { \l_senn_width_int } { \tl_count:n { ##1 } }
     }
   }
 }
\senn_width:N \l_senn_test_seq
\typeout{answer~is~\int_use:N \l_senn_width_int}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Some points to note:

1. Use prefixes.
2. Never allocate variables in functions, unless the functions are specifically designed to allocate variables for *future* usage.
3. You can set a variable using its current value.
4. The function `\tl_count:n` is expandable and can be used in the context of an integer.
5. The main function `\senn_width:N` should be `protected`, as it does assignments to variables.

---

Regarding your problem, something like

```
\int_set:Nn \l_senn_width_int { \senn_width:N \l_senn_test_seq }
```

requires `\senn_width:N` to be fully expandable, which I don't see easily possible.

What you can do is defining a two argument macro:

```
\senn_width_set:NN \l_senn_width_int \l_senn_test_seq
```

so problems with expandability are overcome:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \senn_width_set:NN #1 #2
 {
  \int_set:Nn #1 {-1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #2
   {
    \int_set:Nn #1
     {
      \int_max:nn { #1 } { \tl_count:n { ##1 } }
     }
   }
 }
\senn_width_set:NN \l_senn_width_int \l_senn_test_seq
```